# change position when button clicked?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've two object in android xml, my object locate in horizontal orientation, imageview in left and textview in right,my code look like

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rowFile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_dilvChat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtFileName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"            
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Nama File : test.zip"
                    android:textSize="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i want to switch 2 object when button fire (imageview to right,textview to left)

how i achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do it. Remove the `ImageView` and add it to the `LinearLayout` again. Do this indside the `OnClick` listener.

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rowFile);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_dilvChat);

row.removeView(image);
row.addView(image);

row.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

write these in onClickListener of the Button

```
(findViewById(R.id.imageView)).getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
int imgx = posXY[0];
int imgy = posXY[1];
(findViewById(R.id.textView)).getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
int txtx = posXY[0];
int txty = posXY[1];
(findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setX(txtx);
(findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setY(txty);
(findViewById(R.id.textView)).setX(imgx);
(findViewById(R.id.textView)).setY(imgy);
```